# The chance that all three devices will function, if each fails independently with given probability

Tags: probability

> An orbiting satellite has 3 panels of solar cells, all of which must be activate to provide an adequate power output. The panels function independently of one another. The chance that single panel will fail during the mission is 0.02. What is the probability that there will be adequate power output during the entire mission time?

I could not solve this question from my textbook.

Comment: It is $0.94$ I think

Comment: I dont need directly answer. I need to learn how to solve this question :(

Comment: I have given solution might help

Answer (score 4):

The chance for one panel to work is $1-0.02 = 0.98$. Because you need all three panels to work, the chance for sufficient power is $0.98^3 \approx 0.94$.

Answer (score 2):

The chance that single solar panel will not fail is $p=0.98$. By Bernoulli, the probability that none will fail is $\displaystyle P={3\choose 3}0.98^3\cdot{0.02^0}=0.98^3\approx 0.941$.